# Bitbucket merge recognizes branch changes in one direction but not in the other direction

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I am working with two branches in git, named 'develop' and 'feature'. Feature is my own working branch and develop is used by the whole group. I initially cloned develop into a local repository and created the feature branch from develop:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

I made multiple edits to the feature branch, including making new files, and pushed the branch the the remote repository:

```
git push origin HEAD
```

The develop branch has undergone multiple changes by other group members since I first cloned it.

I am now trying to merge my feature branch in Bitbucket with the group develop branch. When I try to create a pull request, I get a message under the diff tab stating 'There are no changes'. Under the commit tab, I get 'no commits found'.

If I attempt to merge the develop branch into the feature branch, however, many changes and a detailed commit history are reported. Bitbucket flags all the changes I have made in the feature branch for deletion.

I have tried creating a new branch in the local repository from the develop branch, and merging my changes into this branch:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout -b new_branch 
git merge feature
```

I get the message 'Already up-to-date.' and none of my changes are merged.

Can anyone suggest why my branches are failing to merge?

Comment: Did you push your feature branch to the develop branch by mistake? In that case, attempting to merge it into develop again would end up with those results.

Comment: Use `git log` on your develop branch to see if your feature commits are already in the branch.

Comment: Checking the git log in the develop branch, I find an entry that could explain why the merge is not working:
Merge pull request #314 in remove_directory from working_branch to feature. This refers to a working branch that I branched off the feature branch, edited, then merged back to the feature branch. As the feature branch has never been merged into the develop branch, I do not know how this entry can be present in the develop branch log.

Comment: If working_branch is in your develop branch, then it must have been merged into develop at some point. And since working_branch includes the history for feature, that means that develop now has your feature branch.

Comment: About a month ago, I merged develop into feature, then feature into my working branch. I did this so my code would be compatible with the changes other members of the groups had introduced to the develop branch. I continued to modify the working branch until about 10 days ago, when I pushed it to the remote repository, and from there merged it into the feature branch without issue. It is possible that I did not think to  push the updated feature branch to the remote repo. before I did this merge. Could this be the source of the problem? If so, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Basically, from your description, your feature branch made its way into the develop branch and your feature branch is also behind your develop branch. The develop branch doesn't need feature to be merged because it was already merged, but feature needs develop because there are changes in develop that feature doesn't have yet. I don't know how you ended up in this situation or what to suggest... but it would seem that git itself is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One of my colleagues had merged my feature branch into the develop branch,  reverted the merge, then made their own changes to the develop branch. Removing my changes was therefore part of the develop branch history, and was being enacted when I tried to merge feature into develop.

To get around this, I cloned a clean copy of the develop branch and reverted this branch back to the commit just before my feature branch was un-merged. I then merged the reverted branch into the local copy of the feature branch. After resolving conflicts and committing changes, I was able to push my feature branch to the remote server and merge it into the develop branch.

So, the problem arose because git keeps a record of changes created by reverts as well as changes created by merges.